# MySql/PHP SUM 2 tables 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have been having the most difficult time ever with this problem. I have 2 tables with total columns that I want to SUM together. They both have the same columns, I am using two tables as one is a script generated table of data and the other is user entered data and we need them separate. Except now we need to SUM(total) them together.

**Table 1**

```
   +-----------+-----+--------+------+
   | date      |t_id | t_port | total|
   +-----------+-----+--------+------+
   |2012-04-01 | 1271| 101    | 80.00|
   +-----------+-----+--------+------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+----------+------+--------+-------+
| date     | t_id | t_port | total |
+----------+------+--------+-------+
|2012-04-20| 1271 | 101    | 120.00|
+----------+------+--------+-------+
```

Total should be $200.00

HERE IS MY QUERY

```
"SELECT SUM(cntTotal) as total FROM CBS_WO WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthSecond' AND '$monthEnd') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id' UNION SELECT SUM(cntTotal) as total FROM CNT_MODS WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthSecond' AND '$monthEnd') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id'"
```

This query seems to work in phpMyAdmin as I get 2 rows. (1 for each table), logically I used a WHILE loop in PHP to add the two rows together. After echo'ing out each row manually I discovered my second row isn't showing up in the loop, yet it does in the query?

Can't figure out why this is happening, I am certain it's something silly but I been at this code for over 16hrs already and need a new set of eyes.

PHP CODE

```
function periodTotal()
{
    include('/sql.login.php');  

    $t_id                   = "1271";
    $t_port                 = "101";
    $date                   = date("Y-m-d");

    # FIND MONTH (DATE)
    $monthStart     = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00')); 
    $monthFirst     = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+15 days',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));
    $monthSecond    = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+16 days',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));
    $monthEnd       = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));

    if ($date = $monthFirst) 
    {
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(cntTotal) as total FROM CBS_WO WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthStart' AND '$monthFirst') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id' UNION SELECT SUM(cntTotal) as total FROM CNT_MODS WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthStart' AND '$monthFirst') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id'");
        $sql->execute();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(cntTotal) as total FROM CBS_WO WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthSecond' AND '$monthEnd') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id' UNION SELECT SUM(cntTotal) as total FROM CNT_MODS WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthSecond' AND '$monthEnd') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id'");
        $sql->execute();
    }
        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $total += $row['total'];
        }

    return $total;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT SUM(`total`) as `total` FROM ((
    SELECT SUM(cntTotal) as total FROM CBS_WO
    WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthSecond' AND '$monthEnd') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id'
) UNION (
    SELECT SUM(cntTotal) as total FROM CNT_MODS
    WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthSecond' AND '$monthEnd') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id'"
)) as temp
```

This might be more efficient:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM (
    SELECT cntTotal FROM CBS_WO
    WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthSecond' AND '$monthEnd') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id'
) UNION (
    SELECT cntTotal FROM CNT_MODS
    WHERE (date BETWEEN '$monthSecond' AND '$monthEnd') AND t_port = '$t_port' AND t_id = '$t_id'"
) as temp
```

(only has one `SUM`) but you'd have to test it.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly in sql but I can't seem to be able to display it in PHP?

Comment: $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $row['total'];

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems to be able to display your it in PHP......

=>   set the PDO error mode to exception

     $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare(Run Sql Query here...........);

=>   exceute the query 

stmt->execute();

=>by setting the FETCH mode we can set

$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

=> The iterator will fetch the results for us.

 foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) 
        { 
        echo $v; 
        }
```

Comment: Ok, I think I found the issue but not sure how to solve it. I did as you said above and the query error I got was "Every derived table must have its own alias" -- isn't the AS temp at the end of the query the alias?

Comment: **GOT IT!** I used the first query by Frits van Campen's answer and it worked perfectly, for some reason the second one was causing the issue. THANK YOU! for all the help and answers.